# MySQL DATEDIFF function VS compare INTERVAL DAY

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization, where-clause

What is the difference between DATEDIFF function and subtract INTERVAL DAY directly?

1. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), publish_date) <= 3`
2. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE publish_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY`

Result data are the same, but it seems `2.` way is a bit faster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first expression, that uses `DATEDIFF()` requires applying the date function on each and every row *before* the filtering can happen.

By contrast, the second expression does not imply such pre-processing: `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY` is computed just once, and then compared directly against the value of `publish_date`. This predicate can take advantage of an index on the date column. This is the right way to do it.

In technical terms, we say that the second predicate is *sargable*, while the first one isn't: this stands for *Search ARGument ABLE*

As a rule of thumb: do not apply functions the column that you filter on if you have a way around.

Comment: thanks for clear explanation and bring up sargable ^^

Comment: If you have a usable index on `publish_date`, the note about shargeable is far more important to performance than "apply the date function".